# How to save a rating control value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, controls, nsuserdefaults

I am playing around with DYRateView....a control at the end of a long list of controls I've tried out.  It can be found here: https://github.com/dyang/DYRateView

The problem with all the controls I've tried is that I can't seem to save the rating once it's been changed.  I'm using NSUserDefaults and have tried placing it in various places including where the value changes, where the view is set up, in viewDidLoad, in viewWillAppear, within the source code itself.  Saving this value just has me flummoxed.  I would appreciate any help. Just to get a sense of how this should work, I've just been working in the sample code that came with DYRateView. Here is the relevant code:

```
THE .M FILE

#import "DemoViewController.h"

@interface DemoViewController ()

- (void)setUpEditableRateView;

@end

@implementation DemoViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"rating"];

    [self setUpEditableRateView];
}

- (void)setUpEditableRateView {
    DYRateView *rateView = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge.png"]];
    rateView.padding = 20;
    rateView.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
    rateView.editable = YES;
    rateView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:rateView];
    [rateView release];
}

- (void)rateView:(DYRateView *)rateView changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
    self.rateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:rate forKey:@"rating"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

@end
```

Thanks to anyone who takes the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save an `NSNumber` as an `NSInteger`. You should do `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[rate integerValue] forKey:@"rating"];` or use `- setObject:forKey:` because `NSNumber` is an object, not a scalar.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `rating` valuea at: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"rating"];` but what are you doing with this value?

I think that you need to get this value and set to DYRateView. So:

1. Create a property of `DYRateView`: `@property DYRateView * rateView`
2. Set it on `setUpEditableRateView`: `self.rateView = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge.png"]];`
3. Update `self.rateView` (add it to end of `setUpEditableRateView`): `rateView.rate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"rating"]`

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I did as you suggested and a funny thing happened...my view doesn't load.  I just get a black screen.  It seems like it should have worked.  I also tried to recall the default in viewDidLoad and that didn't work either.  Any ideas on what could prevent the view controller to be visible?

Comment: If you are getting a black screen, probably you have an other kind of problem.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to call the default with a property.  That was my first mistake.

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation.